# Communication between Mac and iPhone via USB

Tags: iphone, cocoa

How can I make my mac application's label simply say "iPhone is connected" when the iPhone is plugged in via USB, and then say "iPhone is not connected" when the iPhone is unplugged?

Comment: Probably a bit overkill, but you may want to take a look at [peertalk](https://github.com/rsms/peertalk) which provides an iOS and OS X Cocoa library for communicating over USB and TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://bitbucket.org/tristero/ipodaccessframework

Instances of the IPodAccessAppDelegate class gets notified when iDevices are connected/disconnected.

Note, you won't get applications doing this stuff into the App Store because it's all relying on private frameworks that Apple don't sanction the use of.